# How does one prove one's residency to a given US state when flying to Costa Rica?

Tags: usa, air-travel, covid-19, residency, costa-rica

I read on :

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php (-> Costa Rica):

> Costa Rica. > Published 15.10.2020.
>
> 1. Passengers are not allowed to enter.
>
> - This does not apply to:
>
>   [...]
> - residents of the following states of the United States: Arizona, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Florida, Georgia, Maine, Maryland,
>   Massachusetts, Michigan, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New
>   York, Ohio, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, Texas, Vermont,
>   Virginia, Washington, Washington D.C. and Wyoming;

How does one prove one's residency to a given US state when flying to Costa Rica?

Comment: Essentially all people resident in the US have state-issued identification, whether it is a driver license or an equivalent non-driver state identification. Surely they would just ask? *"Where do you live?"* "Uh, Connectichusetts?" *"Can I see your state ID?"*

Comment: @GregHewgill I don't have the exact stats, but some citizens lacking state IDs is the reason why voting ID laws are currently controversial. But of course these people are probably not flying to Costa Rica.

Comment: @JonathanReez I didn't have a state ID during my first year of residency in the US. Not much useful if not driving or drinking without passport. Also, I can keep my driving ID even if I don't reside in the US state that issued my driving ID, so not a great proof of residence. But looks like that's what Costa Rica uses anyway.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: If you can't provide any proof that you live in a certain state (even if that proof does not reflect reality, like you just moved states), then Costa Rica does not have to let you in. Entry is a privilege, not a right.

Comment: @GregHewgill sure

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - “I can keep my driving ID even if I don't reside in the US state that issued my driving ID“ - While this statement is technically true, it is misleading. You can physically retain possession of a state issued drivers license or ID when you leave that state. But, after 30 days, that DL/ID becomes invalid for most states. Most states have a requirement that the address shown on your DL/ID must be your permanent address of residency on record. If you change addresses, you have to update your DL/ID within the state mandated time limit. Otherwise, it becomes invalid.

Comment: @DeanF. that is a complex subject. I.e. California requires a lot of paperwork to stop being a resident, simply moving out for 30 days without establishing permanent residency is not sufficient. I think it would be a great Law.SE question!

Comment: @JonathanReez Here's a money.SE post on CA tax residency https://money.stackexchange.com/q/126904/5656 0 day is enough to be tax resident.

Comment: @JonathanReez - The post that Franck linked above makes it sound like a domicile issue. In other words, where is your address of permanent residency on record. A good example of this is someone serving in the US military. Where they choose to call their permanent residency may have nothing to do with where they are currently stationed. But, once they formally change their residency, they will have to change their state ID.

Comment: I travelled to Germany at a time where admissability from the US was also based on state of residence. However they didn't check at the border at all.  They simply relied on people honoring the requirements but their where no controls or checks whatsoever.

Comment: @DeanF. in reality people moving and not updating their ID for more than a month happens all the time, regardless of what you are 'supposed' to do.  it rarely becomes an issue (until you need to renew registration or something like that), even if you get pulled over by police  (who will most likely treat it as a valid license regardless of what the law technically says).

Comment: plus, if someone wanted to, they could always keep their old license from the previous state, so it's not a very good check for where the person residence is.  The truth is almost all covid related restrictions around the world heavily depend on the honor system.

Comment: @DeanF. Costa Rica wouldn't have that access though.

Comment: @eps Reminds me of an episode of either Top Gear or The Grand Tour where James May was talking to someone about driving with a suspended license, and the person just couldn't accept the idea that _anyone_ would drive without a valid license, because it's illegal.

Comment: Car drive with _gas_, not with licenses...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [Costa Rica Tourism Board:](https://www.visitcostarica.com/en/costa-rica/statement-costa-rica-tourism-board-covid-19)

> Passengers coming from the U.S. must show through their **driver’s license or state identification (State ID)** that they live in one of the authorized states. This requirement excludes children travelling with their family. This requirement will be necessary until Nov. 1.

Note that drivers' licenses are issued by the individual states in the US, not by any sort of federal agency, and they generally list the holder's home address.

After November 1, all US citizens & residents will be welcome to Costa Rica regardless of their place of residence.

Comment: Just to observe that a 'citizen' and a 'resident' are two different things.